# Control used in people hub app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to implement some thing like in people hub native app. I want to open some pop same like they using to select contact alphabetically. can some one tell me how should i start for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the long list selector from http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

In depth here - http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

Comment: Personally, I hope Mango provides a native alternative (or at least some better hooks). I find the scrolling on the long list selector feels very inconsistent with the listbox

Answer (score 0):

First question, why build an app that already exist nativly? Secondly your question is far too broad to answer properly, we cant tell you how to build an app.

I recomend going through the tutorials on the app hub to get you started. Here is also a free book that might help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx

Comment: Because the native app is good but doesn't go far enough and you can't extend it so you have to emulate it. I've completely reproduced the built-in map in one of my apps because people are familiar with it but there are several capabilities missing. As a side note, contrary to popular belief the Bing map widget performs every bit as well as the built-int map when used competently.